# How to execute the find command in a shell script without getting an error message "missing argument to `-execdir'"?

Tags: shell-script, find

This works fine:

```
$ find /home/me/folder -type f -iname "*.rar" -execdir unrar x -o- {} \;
```

However for this script it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/me/folder -type f -iname "*.rar" -execdir unrar x -o- {} \;
```

Can you give me a hint why this error message appears?

```
$ ./unrar_script.sh
find: missing argument to `-execdir'
```

Comment: I fixed your shebang, your script has the correct one, right?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: What version of `find` is it? Are you using OS X?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the shebang in my post. The script is right. It is version 4.7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Max Are the any `.rar` files in the directory? Add `-print` before `-execdir` to see them listed.

Comment: I think in your script you don't give space between {}   \;